# How to publish (sweave) regression formulas?

Tags: r, publish, regression, sweave

How can I publish a regression formula nicely?

```
fit1<-dynlm(dep~indep1+indep2+indep3)
s1<-summary(fit1)
s1$call
```

How can I Sweave `s1$call` ? I mean I do not want to have somethin like `dynlm(formula=dep~indep1+indep2+indep3)´ in my pdf document. I´d prefer to have a more textbook style over this function call style. Plus I´d like to (manually?) add intercept and errorterm to the model (because it's actually in there).

Note that I found `outreg` on google (which seems a little bit too heavyweighted right now) and not exactly fitting my needs at first sight.

EDIT: Trying to post sample output, actually I´d love to, but I don't know how to do it better with the SO editor:

```
 dep = alpha + beta_1*indep1 + beta_2*indep2 + beta_3*indep3 + epsilon
```

Some matrix notation would also be fine, but printing the model definition would be nice no matter how. Of course adding it manually is also possible, but when you are in a robustness check phase the model variables might change often and the documentation has got to be up to date.

(Using http://texify.com :)

[image: img]http://www.texify.com/img/%5CLARGE%5C%21%5Cmbox%7Bdep%7D%20%3D%20%5Calpha%20%2B%20%5Cbeta_1%20%5Ccdot%20%5Cmbox%7Bindep1%7D%20%2B%20%5Cbeta_2%20%5Ccdot%20%5Cmbox%7Bindep2%7D%20%2B%20%5Cepsilon.gif[/img]

Comment: I don't know of any canned solution. I would suggest putting together an appropriate translator (using `paste`, `gsub`, etc. -- be careful to escape backslashes where necessary!), creating the LaTeX string you want, and then using `results=tex` in your Sweave options for the relevant chunk (I don't know offhand if you can get the equivalent of `results=tex` in an `\Sexpr` expression ...)

Comment: PS `\Sexpr` results are included verbatim, so my comment about `results=tex` is irrelevant.  This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406071/r-sweave-latex-escape-variables-to-be-printed-in-latex

Comment: I am a little puzzled that there's nothing out of the box. Probably will have to do something on my own, but thanks to all your answers, particularly the pastin and gsubbing it should be manageable. It will be hard to accept ONE answer in the end :)

Comment: It's actually not entirely clear what output you want.  Could you post sample output?

Comment: Thanks Ben! I hate the fact that I have to write this gibberish right here just to say thanks Ben, cause SO needs some more characters :)

Answer (score 5):

This Rnw file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
data("USDistLag", package = "lmtest")
library(dynlm)
dfm1 <- dynlm(consumption ~ gnp + L(consumption), data = USDistLag)
@ 

<<echo=FALSE>>=
cc <-dfm1$call
f <- cc$formula
LHS <- as.character(f)[2]
RHS <- as.character(f)[3]
coefs <- gsub(" +","",strsplit(RHS,"\\+")[[1]])
mbox <- function(x) { paste("\\\\mbox{",x,"}",sep="") }
pars <- paste("\\\\beta_",0:(length(coefs)-1),sep="")
p <- paste(mbox(LHS),"=",paste(pars,mbox(coefs),sep=" \\\\cdot ",collapse="+"),
           "+ \\\\epsilon")
@ 

$$
\Sexpr{p}
$$
\end{document}
```

leads to this TeX fragment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> data("USDistLag", package = "lmtest")
> library(dynlm)
> dfm1 <- dynlm(consumption ~ gnp + L(consumption), data = USDistLag)
\end{Sinput}
\end{Schunk}


$$
\mbox{consumption} = \beta_0 \cdot \mbox{gnp}+\beta_1 \cdot \mbox{L(consumption)} + \epsilon
$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I run that code, I get the following TeX fragment: `$$
\Sexpr{\\\\mbox{consumption} = \\\\beta_0 \\\\cdot \\\\mbox{gnp}+\\\\beta_1 \\\\cdot \\\\mbox{L(consumption)} + \\\\epsilon}
$$
`

Comment: How did you run it? Works for me -- I copied the text to a file `Sweavetmp.Rnw` and tried both (from the command line) `R CMD Sweave Sweavetmp.Rnw` and (from the R prompt) `Sweave("Sweavetmp.Rnw")`.  Got a sensible `Sweavetmp.tex` file with single backslashes, which could be `pdflatex`ed just fine.

Comment: @ Ben Bolker: I'm using the "compile pdf" option in Rstudio, which I think is causing the issue.

Comment: maybe you could ask on the Rstudio help forum at http://support.rstudio.org/ . The developers are usually pretty responsive ...

Answer (score 3):

I found this function I wrote when I was taking an intro class to regression modeling. I'm sure it's less than optimal, but it worked well enough for that course. If nothing else, maybe this will get you pointed in the right direction to take it further.

```
writeCoef <- function(x) {
  require(plyr)

    coefnames <- as.data.frame(coef(x))
    coefnames$betas <- row.names(coefnames) 
    coefnames <- adply(coefnames, 1, function(x) paste(round(x[1],3), x[2] , sep = " * "))

    dependent <- paste(as.character(x$call$formula)[2], " = ", sep = "")

    ret <- paste(dependent, paste(coefnames[,3], sep = "", collapse = " + "))
    ret <- gsub("\\*\\s\\(Intercept\\)", "", ret)
  return(ret)
    }
```

And in action:

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2,10,20, labels=c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)

> writeCoef(lm.D9)
[1] "weight =  5.032 + -0.371 * groupTrt"
```

Comment: it's nice, but it doesn't sound like what the OP wants -- i.e. the theoretical formula for the regression, not the estimated coefficients and so forth

Answer (score 0):

This short Rnw file demonstrates printing out a long regression formula, wrapping over multiple lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<Printmodel,echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
#Specify any formula
model1 <- formula("outcome ~ (variable1 +variable2 + variable3 + variable4 + variable5 + variable6 )^2 + variable7 + variable8 + variable7 * variable8")

#Converts formula to LaTeX
cat(paste("\\begin{dmath*}\n",gsub("~","\\\\sim",deparse(model1,width.cutoff = 500L)),"\n\\end{dmath*}",sep=""))
@

\end{document}
```

The resulting LaTeX code is:

```
\begin{dmath*}
outcome \sim (variable1 + variable2 + variable3 + variable4 + variable5 + variable6)^2 + variable7 + variable8 + variable7 * variable8
\end{dmath*}
```

which wraps nicely over multiple lines, by using the breqn package and the dmath environment.