# Pass underscore as inline code to knitR

Tags: r, knitr

I'm using knitR to generate a document. Some of the variable names have underscores that I can't change. Anyway to still insert these as normal text?

Basic example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
data.df = data.frame(var_name_1=c(0,1),var_name_2=c(1,2))
@
I want to be able to print \Sexpr{(names(data.df)[1])} and \Sexpr{(names(data.df)[2])} normally.

\end{document}
```

Tkanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suitable work around is to define the function `rep_` in the code block. `rep_` just looks for the underscore and places a "\" before it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
data.df = data.frame(var_name_1=c(0,1),var_name_2=c(1,2))
rep_ = function(test){gsub("([_])", '\\\\\\_', "test_var")}
@
I want to be able to print \Sexpr{rep_((names(data.df)[1]))} and \Sexpr{rep_((names(data.df)[2]))} normally.

\end{document}
```

Resulting in what we want!

Comment: By the way, using a regular expression like in this answer seems to be the usual solution to this issue, see [Yihui's answer here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Sweave-printing-an-underscore-in-the-output-from-an-R-command-td4675177.html#a4675200). [Aaron's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5407326/2706569) could also be helpful (though tailored for Sweave) because it sanitizes `_` as well as `&`.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't spotted those before posting the question, my googling powers appear to still be lacking :P. Cheers!