# Inline code with underscore in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I would like to insert functions named "test_sample()" as inline R code in a LaTeX+knitr document.

Simply including `\Sexpr{'test_sample()'}` results in `Missing $` errors.

I found the following directly related questions:
[Pass underscore as inline code to knitR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550225/pass-underscore-as-inline-code-to-knitr?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But already copying the code in the answer there does not work for me: I get an R warning message:

```
In hilight(code, "latex", ...) :
  the syntax of the source code is invalid; the fallback mode is used
```

and in LaTeX still a `Missing $` error.

I tried adopting it by

```
<<>>=
test_ = function(x){gsub("([_])", '\\\\\\_', "test_x")}
@
\Sexpr{test_(sample)}
```

but this stilll results in the same error(s).

If I manually place an escape character `\` in front of th `_` in the tex file produced by knitr, it works, but I can't figure out how to do this automatically.

I also get the the same error when I copy-paste the solution from this question: [R, Sweave, LaTeX - escape variables to be printed in LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406071/r-sweave-latex-escape-variables-to-be-printed-in-latex/5407326#5407326)

```
<<echo=FALSE>>=
sanitize <- function(str) {
  result <- str
  result <- gsub("&", "\\\\&", result, fixed = TRUE)
  result <- gsub("_", "\\\\_", result, fixed = TRUE)
  result
}
@ 

<<>>=
(foo <- "test & _")
sanitize(foo)
@ 

When sanitized, it's ``\Sexpr{sanitize(foo)}''.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the parentheses with braces?   \Sexpr{'test_sample()'}   Also, the underscore may require an escape character before it, e.g. \_

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well, but it also results in an `Missing $` error. If I manually place an escape character like `\` in the tex file generated by knitr, then it works, but I can't figure out how to do that automatically. I just just place it in the R code, this leads to R syntax errors and the code can't be compiled

Comment: I just tried it with "test\\_sample()" -- two backslashes - and it worked

Comment: @lawyeR So you mean `\Sexpr{"test\\_sample()"}` in the Rnw file? This leads to a warning in R for me: `In hilight(code, "latex", ...) :
  the syntax of the source code is invalid; the fallback mode is used`, and in the tex file: `test\textbackslash{}\hlkwd{_sample}()`, however, this can't be compiled (Missing $ error). It only works if I manually change the tex file to `\hlkwd{test\_sample}()`

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really have anything to do with `knitr` or R, it's all about inserting an underscore in LaTeX.  The simplest way to do that is to put it in a `\verb` command, e.g.

```
When sanitized, it's ``\verb!\Sexpr{sanitize(foo)}!''.
```

After `knitr` runs, this gets turned into

```
When sanitized, it's ``\verb!test \\& \\_!''.
```

and that displays what you probably want, i.e.
[image]

You could change the `sanitize()` function to add the `\verb` wrapper if you want.  Anything to produce the "After" line.

Edited to add:

If you really want to keep the code highlighting, you need to do something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70652/alltt-packages-alltt-makes-a-newline to create a macro that does some of what `\verb` does, but not all.  This will also require changes to your
sanitize function.

Comment: The code I pasted in the original question leads to the R warning `In hilight(code, "latex", ...) :
  the syntax of the source code is invalid; the fallback mode is used
`, and not the desired output, but ```\verb!test \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}& \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}_!''` in LaTeX instead. Just to be clear, the output I want in the tex file after processing with knitr is `\hlkwd{test\_sample}()`

Comment: That's strange; it doesn't happen to me.  Could you post a complete .Rnw file?  It may be a bug in the `hilight()` function; what package is that from?

Comment: I can reproduce an error like that if I use the wrong number of escapes, e.g. `'\\\\\_'` gives the error, because it's not legal syntax.  You need an even number of backslashes.

Comment: It seems to happen to me also when I use an even number of backslashes, I simply copied the code posted above and it did result in that error. The `hilight()` function is a function from the highlight package. I have no package loaded other than `knitr`. If I find some time, I will try to reproduce the error in a complete Rnw file that I can post here. For now, I used a workaround by manually defining a LaTeX command `\newcommand{\test}{\hlkwd{test\_sample}()}`

Comment: You did not "simply copy the code posted", because the posted code is not a complete Rnw file.  The error likely occured elsewhere in whatever code you did run.  It would only happen in a code block, not an `\Sexpr` expression, where `knitr` doesn't call `hilight`.

Comment: That is true. I did define `knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) { 
  if (is.numeric(x)) return(knitr:::format_sci(x, 'latex')) 
  highr:::hi_latex(x) 
}) ` in the preamble to obtain the same syntax highlighting for inline code as well.